# sql server Convert varchar to be float causing issue

Tags: sql-server

I got this error when trying to convert varchar to float using cast or convert:

> Error converting data type varchar to float.

Can someone please help?

Code:

```
SELECT  convert(float,isnull(output2,0) ) YTD 
FROM A
```

`output2` is a `varchar` column in table `A`.

Comment: You are using `,` instead of `.` on the varchar value?

Comment: You may try to execute `SELECT output2 FROM A WHERE try_convert(float,isnull(output2,0) ) IS NULL` to get the wrong values.

Comment: What kind of data in the `output2` column? Non-numeric data won't convert very well, e.g.: `select convert(float, 'lorem ipsum')`

Comment: Provide table structrue and example for output2 - otherwise no one can answer this question.

Comment: As in your previous question on the same issue - use try_convert. And THINK about your code. We know output2 is varchar, so you should be replacing NULL values with the string constant of '0' and not the integer constant. Here you get lucky and your integer constant is implicitly converted to varchar. You may not be lucky next time.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning You are right. That's the reason why it failed. Originally I thought that column only have numbers.

Answer (score 0):

solved. Turns out that output2 column has some non-numeric data that's why it failed